# MySQL Query working on one server and not on other - Problems in new server

Tags: mysql, sql, percona

I am transferring my site from one development site to another.

Everything is working except the following SQL

```
(SELECT "1" AS type, `m`.`id`, `m`.`package_name`, `m`.`ending_city`, `m`.`discount_type`, `m`.`discount_amount`, (SELECT image_name FROM `package_images` WHERE package_type="1" AND package_id=m.id AND is_temp="0" ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) AS package_image, (SELECT adult_price FROM `tour_package_price` WHERE package_id=m.id AND package_type="1" AND price_type="1") AS package_price, `c`.`city_name` FROM (`tour_package_master` m) JOIN `city` c ON `c`.`id`=`m`.`ending_city` LEFT JOIN (`tour_package_date_range` d) ON m.id=d.tour_package_id WHERE `d`.`tour_start_date`>=NOW() AND `m`.`active_status` = "1" GROUP BY `m`.`id`) UNION ALL (SELECT "2" AS type, `m`.`id`, `m`.`package_name`, `m`.`ending_city`, `m`.`discount_type`, `m`.`discount_amount`, (SELECT image_name FROM `package_images` WHERE package_type="2" AND package_id=m.id AND is_temp="0" ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) AS package_image, (SELECT adult_price FROM `tour_package_price` WHERE package_id=m.id AND package_type="2" AND price_type="1") AS package_price, `c`.`city_name` FROM (`weekend_tour_package_master` m) JOIN `city` c ON `c`.`id`=`m`.`ending_city` WHERE `m`.`tour_start_date`>=NOW() AND `m`.`active_status` = "1" GROUP BY `m`.`id`)
```

You can check the running SQL at this url

http://travelindia.india-web-design.com/welcome/test_query

when you click on the you will see the sql executing correctly.

But the same query is not working on the new server. 
You can check at

http://travelindia.staging-websites.com/welcome/test_query

Its getting a syntax error:

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN `city` c ON `c`.`id`=`m`.`ending_city` WHERE `m`.`tour_start_date`>=NOW() A' at line 1
```

You can check by clicking on the button.

Please find a comparison of the mysql server versions

Current Server Configurations:

Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.5.42-cll - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

New Server Configurations:

Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: Percona Server
Server version: 5.5.31-30.3-log - Percona Server (GPL), Release rel30.3, Revision 520
Protocol version: 10

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the sql in question and the error message.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to expose those links? Everyone can access your database and execute arbitrary SQL commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess **MySQL** supports `FROM (tour_package_master m)` but may be **Percona Server** doesn't support like `(FROM tour_package_master m)` change it to `FROM tour_package_master m`

Note: Remove `(` and `)`.

Change following lines in your query.

```
FROM (`tour_package_master` m)
FROM (`weekend_tour_package_master` m)

To

FROM `tour_package_master` m
FROM `weekend_tour_package_master` m
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the reason could be that you use `JOIN`-clauses in your 
mysql-query that some versions of persona do not support.

You will have to rewrite your query without using JOIN-clauses.